# Using power series to solve differential equations of high order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have to solve this different equation with the help of power series

$y''+y'+y = x+\frac{1}{3}x^{3}+\frac{1}{5}x^{5}...$

Let $y = \sum_{0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$

$y' = \sum_{1}^{\infty}n\cdot a_{n}x^{n-1}$

$y'' = \sum_{2}^{\infty}n\cdot(n-1)\cdot a_{n}x^{n-2}$

Now the exponents in $x^{n}$ of all the derivatives must be the same for $y'$ $n\rightarrow n+1$

$y' = \sum_{0}^{\infty}(n+1)\cdot a_{n+1}x^{n}$

and for $y''$ $n\rightarrow n+2$

$y'' = \sum_{2}^{\infty}(n+2)\cdot(n+1)\cdot a_{n+2}x^{n}$ $\rightarrow \sum_{0}^{\infty}[a_{n}+(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}]x^n =$

Now if we had 0 instead of $x+\frac{1}{3}x^{3}+\frac{1}{5}x^{5}...$ then we could find the first 4 non zero coefficients but now how do I continue?

Comment: Note that 
$$z+\frac{1}{3}z^3+\frac{1}{5}z^5+\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2k-1}}{2k-1}  =\operatorname{arctanh}(z) \\ z\in\Bbb B(0,1)\setminus\{1\}$$

Comment: Your title ends with "differential equations of high order", so I clicked on your question because I was curious how high "high" is for your ODE -- an order of around $5$ or $6,$ an order of around $12$ or $15,$ an order in the $20$'s, $\ldots$ ? Since this is only a 2nd order ODE, maybe you should change the title. Perhaps use this: "How to solve a 2nd order constant coefficient ODE whose inhomogeneous term is a specified power series?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y^{\prime \prime}+y^{\prime}+y-\mathrm{arctanh} \left(x \right)=0}
\end{gather*}
With the expansion point for the power series method at $x = 0$.

Since $x = 0$ is an ordinary point, then standard power series can be used.
$$
y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} x^{n}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
        y^{\prime} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n} x^{n -1}\\ 
        y^{\prime \prime} &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n \left(n -1\right) a_{n} x^{n -2}
\end{align*}
Substituting the above back into the ode gives
\begin{align*}
        \left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n \left(n -1\right) a_{n} x^{n -2}\right)+\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n} x^{n -1}\right)+\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} x^{n}\right)=\mathrm{arctanh} \left(x \right) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Expanding $\mathrm{arctanh} \left(x \right)$ as Taylor series around $x=0$ and keeping only
the first few terms gives
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{arctanh} \left(x \right) &= x +\frac{1}{3} x^{3}+\frac{1}{5} x^{5}+\frac{1}{7} x^{7} + \dots \\ 
\end{align*}
Hence the ODE in Eq (1) becomes
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n \left(n -1\right) a_{n} x^{n -2}\right)+\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n} x^{n -1}\right)+\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} x^{n}\right) = x +\frac{1}{3} x^{3}+\frac{1}{5} x^{5}+\frac{1}{7} x^{7}\tag{2} 
\end{align*}
The next step is to make all powers of $x$ be $n$ in each summation term.
Going over each summation term above with power of $x$ in it which is not
already $x^{n}$ and adjusting  the power and the corresponding index gives
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n \left(n -1\right) a_{n} x^{n -2} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n +2\right) a_{n +2} \left(n +1\right) x^{n} \\
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n a_{n} x^{n -1} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n +1\right) a_{n +1} x^{n} 
\end{align*}
Substituting all the above in Eq (2) gives the following equation where
now all powers of $x$ are the same and equal to $n$.
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n +2\right) a_{n +2} \left(n +1\right) x^{n}\right)+\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(n +1\right) a_{n +1} x^{n}\right)+\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} x^{n}\right) = x +\frac{1}{3} x^{3}+\frac{1}{5} x^{5}+\frac{1}{7} x^{7}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
For $0\le n$, the recurrence equation is
\begin{align*}
\left(\left(n +2\right) a_{n +2} \left(n +1\right)+\left(n +1\right) a_{n +1}+a_{n}\right) x^{n} = x +\frac{1}{3} x^{3}+\frac{1}{5} x^{5}+\frac{1}{7} x^{7}            \tag{4} 
\end{align*}
For $n = 0$ the recurrence equation gives
\begin{align*}
2 a_{2}+a_{1}+a_{0} &= 0
\end{align*}
Or
\begin{align*}
                    a_{2} &= -\frac{a_{1}}{2}-\frac{a_{0}}{2}            
\end{align*}
For $n = 1$ the recurrence equation gives
\begin{align*}
\left(6 a_{3}+2 a_{2}+a_{1}\right) x&=x\\
                  6 a_{3}+2 a_{2}+a_{1} = 1
\end{align*}
Which after substituting the earlier terms found becomes
\begin{align*}
                    a_{3} = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{a_{0}}{6}            
\end{align*}
For $n = 2$ the recurrence equation gives
\begin{align*}
\left(12 a_{4}+3 a_{3}+a_{2}\right) x^{2}&=0\\
12 a_{4}+3 a_{3}+a_{2} &= 0
\end{align*}
Which after substituting the earlier terms found becomes
\begin{align*}
                    a_{4} &= -\frac{1}{24}+\frac{a_{1}}{24}            
\end{align*}
For $n = 3$ the recurrence equation gives
\begin{align*}
\left(20 a_{5}+4 a_{4}+a_{3}\right) x^{3}&=\frac{x^{3}}{3}\\
20 a_{5}+4 a_{4}+a_{3} &= {\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align*}
Which after substituting the earlier terms found becomes
\begin{align*}
a_{5} &= \frac{1}{60}-\frac{a_{1}}{120}-\frac{a_{0}}{120}            
\end{align*}
For $n = 4$ the recurrence equation gives
\begin{align*}
                 \left(30 a_{6}+5 a_{5}+a_{4}\right) x^{4}&=0\\
                  30 a_{6}+5 a_{5}+a_{4} &= 0
\end{align*}
Which after substituting the earlier terms found becomes
\begin{align*}
a_{6} &= -\frac{1}{720}+\frac{a_{0}}{720}            
\end{align*}
And so on...

Therefore the solution is
\begin{align*}
y &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} x^{n}\\ 
   &= a_{3} x^{3}+a_{2} x^{2}+a_{1} x +a_{0} + \dots
\end{align*}
Substituting the values for $a_{n}$ found above, the solution becomes
\begin{align*}
y &= a_{0}+a_{1} x +\left(-\frac{a_{1}}{2}-\frac{a_{0}}{2}\right) x^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{a_{0}}{6}\right) x^{3}+\left(-\frac{1}{24}+\frac{a_{1}}{24}\right) x^{4}+\left(\frac{1}{60}-\frac{a_{1}}{120}-\frac{a_{0}}{120}\right) x^{5}+\left(-\frac{1}{720}+\frac{a_{0}}{720}\right) x^{6}+\left(\frac{23}{5040}+\frac{a_{1}}{5040}\right) x^{7}+\dots
\end{align*}
Collecting terms, the solution becomes
\begin{align*}
                y = \left(1-\frac{1}{2} x^{2}+\frac{1}{6} x^{3}-\frac{1}{120} x^{5}+\frac{1}{720} x^{6}\right) a_{0}+\left(x -\frac{1}{2} x^{2}+\frac{1}{24} x^{4}-\frac{1}{120} x^{5}+\frac{1}{5040} x^{7}\right) a_{1}+\frac{x^{3}}{6}-\frac{x^{4}}{24}+\frac{x^{5}}{60}-\frac{x^{6}}{720}+\frac{23 x^{7}}{5040}+O\left(x^{8}\right)
\end{align*}
At $x = 0$ the solution above becomes
\begin{align*}
y &= \left(1-\frac{1}{2} x^{2}+\frac{1}{6} x^{3}-\frac{1}{120} x^{5}+\frac{1}{720} x^{6}\right) y \left(0\right)+\left(x -\frac{1}{2} x^{2}+\frac{1}{24} x^{4}-\frac{1}{120} x^{5}+\frac{1}{5040} x^{7}\right) y^{\prime}\left(0\right)+\frac{x^{3}}{6}-\frac{x^{4}}{24}+\frac{x^{5}}{60}-\frac{x^{6}}{720}+\frac{23 x^{7}}{5040}+O\left(x^{8}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: WolframAlpha finds the particular solution  (plus the homogenous solution) completely: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%2By%27%2By%3Darctanhx

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous equation
$$u''+u'+u=0$$
Is solved very easily with exponentials, so let's find a particular solution to
$$u''(x)+u'(x)+u(x)=\operatorname{arctanh}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$$
Using a power series. First, we remark that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k-1}x^{2k-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}x^n$$
Now,
$$u(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n  \\ u'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n \\ u''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}x^n$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(a_n+(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}\big)x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}x^n\tag{1}$$
Because the right hand side has no constant term, the left must be the same:
$$a_0+a_{1}+2a_2=0\tag{2}$$
We can give this whatever initial values we want, so let's pick for instance $u'(0)=u(0)=0$.
From this we get
$$a_0=a_1=0$$
Which, from $(2)$, gives us $a_2=0$ as well.
Going back to $(1)$ we as well we get the recurrence
$$a_n+(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}$$
Rearranging,
$$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n}-(n+1)a_{n+1}-a_n \\ a_{n+2}=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n(n+1)(n+2)}-\frac{1}{n+2}a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_n $$
Shifting the index,
$$a_n=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2n(n-1)(n-2)}-\frac{1}{n}a_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}a_{n-2}$$
From this we can easily generate the coefficients quickly using python, for instance

```
import numpy as np
nmax=10
a=np.zeros(nmax)
a[0]=0
a[1]=0
a[2]=0
for n in range(3,nmax):
    a[n]=(1-(-1)**n)/(2*n*(n-1)*(n-2))-a[n-1]/n-a[n-2]/(n*(n-1))
print(str(a))
```

Returns the output

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.16666667 -0.04166667  0.01666667
 -0.00138889  0.00456349 -0.00054563  0.00198137]
```

These are the values of $(a_n)_{0\leq n\leq 9}$.

Then you can plot it,

```
def f(x):
    return sum(a[n]*x**n for n in range(0,nmax))
x=np.arange(-0.99,1,0.010)
plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.xlim([-1,1])
plt.ylim([-0.25,0.25])
plt.title("Approximate solution of $u''(x)+u'(x)+u(x)=tanh^{-1}(x)$ with $u(0)=u'(0)=0$ up to $O(x^{10})$")
```

Output:

[image: plot]